# C# - GroupPrincipal.GetMembers(true) - which group?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

So I'm trying to get something going with enumerating AD group membership recursively. At the moment I have...

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mine.domain.com");
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "myADGroup");
if (grp != null)
{
    foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
}
```

This all works great, of course. It lists every user who is a member of the group and all the users who are members of groups nested within, however many nesting levels deep that may be. Which is great.

What I really need is to know *what* group in this little nesting the user came from.

```
GRP-MainProject
   -- GRP-Producers
   -- GRP-Artists
     -- UserA
```

Running my current query against GRP-MainProject will return UserA - how should I go about returning the user and the fact that it was GRP-Artists which he inherited membership of GRP-MainProject from?

UserA is a member of about 40 groups or so, in case that matters. *Edit - worth mentioning the user could have membership of the group from multiple nested groups.*

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you already know its in this line foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(true)) just output the the grp together with your p.Name

Comment: When I output the grp, it just outputs "GRP-MainProject" as the group for UserA, whereas I need to return GRP-Artists as the users group. Because the bool value for GetMembers is true, the recursive output of it just counts all users within it as being in the GRP-MainProject, regardless of the actual nested group membership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this maybe:

Declare Static List of Group Objects (simple class of GroupPrincipal, integer level, and parent GroupPrincipal)

```
public class SomeDirTraverser
{
    private static List<GroupObj> _groups = new List<GroupObj>();

    public List<string> GetMembershipWithPath(string groupname)
    {
        List<string> retVal = new List<string>();

        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, groupname);
        if (grp != null)
        {
            BuildHList(grp, 0, null);
            foreach (UserPrincipal usr in grp.GetMembers(true))
                retVal.Add(GetMbrPath(usr));
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    private void BuildHList(GroupPrincipal node, int level, GroupPrincipal parent)
    {
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> rslts = node.GetMembers();
        _groups.Add(new GroupObj() { Group = node, Level = level, Parent = parent });
        foreach (GroupPrincipal grp in rslts.Where(g => g is GroupPrincipal))
            BuildHList(grp, level + 1, node);
    }

    private string GetMbrPath(UserPrincipal usr)
    {
        Stack<string> output = new Stack<string>();
        StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder();
        GroupObj fg = null, tg = null;
        output.Push(usr.Name);
        foreach (GroupObj go in _groups)
        {
            if (usr.IsMemberOf(go.Group))
            {
                output.Push(go.Group.Name);
                fg = go;
                while (fg.Parent != null)
                {
                    output.Push(fg.Parent.Name);
                    tg = (from g in _groups where g.Group == fg.Parent select g).FirstOrDefault();
                    fg = tg;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        while (output.Count > 1)
            retVal.AppendFormat("{0} ->", output.Pop());
        retVal.Append(output.Pop());

        return retVal.ToString();
    }
}

public class GroupObj
{
    public GroupPrincipal Group { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public GroupPrincipal Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This one looks like it should give you what you want.

Comment: This could work. I need to play with it a little, as the output just needs to be GroupPrincipal-->GroupPrincipal-->UserPrincipal where UserPrincipal u == "Joe Blogs" - I'll play tomorrow hopefully. Thanks.

Comment: So, this has the basics of it, but ultimately it's just dumping group memebership out recursively. I'm struggling to figure out how to pass a username to it and have it return the GroupPrincipal objects that hold that username in relation to this username. High level end goal is to answer the question "UserA has access to this folder - from where does he get this?"

Comment: @dotalchemy ok, I understand what you are looking for now.  I'll update my answer in a few minutes and see if I can get it closer

Comment: output.Push(fg.Parent.Name);
       fg = fg.Parent;

Seems to be assigning a GroupPrincipal to the GroupObj - is something missing there?

Comment: @dotalchemy no, that was my mistake.  I made this one into a class and tried it on my AD.  It works, but is painfully slow, of course my AD has around 15000 users.  Not a bad solution for a report sort of export, but pretty bad if it's somehting you need to generate on the fly like data for a webpage.

Comment: that's some fine work there :-) Upvoting, will accept as answer and see if I can flag to get the expired bounty awarded to you. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Know this ones old, but like to give credit where its due.  Getting what I need, working on outputting it to a format I can import to SQL DB,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mine.domain.com");
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "myADGroup");
if (grp != null)
{
    foreach (UserPrincipal user in grp.GetMembers(true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User: {0}", user.Name);
        foreach (Principal userGroup in user.GetGroups(ctx))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   - Member of Group: {0}", userGroup.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a good idea if you could somehow add a check to test whether `userGroup` is a member of `grp` before outputting the info...